# Loop through functions in a class

Tags: python, numpy, class, oop, numpy-ndarray

I have several functions inside a class that I applied augmentation to a numpy image array. I would like to know how to loop through all of them and apply those. For example:

```
Class Augmentation():
    def rotation(data):
      return rotated_image
    def shear(data):
      return sheared_image
    def elasticity(data):
      return enlarged_image
A=Augmentation()
```

My end result should be stacking all my functions. So for example: my data is (64,64) in shape. So after all my augmentations I should have a final numpy of (12,64,64). I currently tried creating different functions and then used

```
stack_of_images = np.stack(f1,f2,f3,....,f12)
stack_of_images.shape = (12,64,64)
```

I am using 12 different functions to augmentate numpy image arrays. I insert 1 image (64,64) and I get 12 images stacked (12,64,64).

Comment: Is the input variable `data` the same for all twelve functions?

Comment: `[f(data) for f in [list,of,functions]]`

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, the data is the same for all functions, data is original dataset and the rest of functions are for example: rotation 90 degrees, shear, rotation 45 degrees, etc.

Comment: Write a thirteenth wrapper function that calls the twelve other functions and returns their results in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the attribute dictionary of the type.
You can either get it with `vars(Augmentation)` or `Augmentation.__dict__`. Then, just iterate through the dict, and check for functions with `callable`.

NOTE: querying `vars(A)` or `A.__dict__` (note it's the instance, not the class), will NOT include anything defined in the class, and in this case would be just `{}`. You don't even have to create an instance in the first place.

NOTE2: It seems like you should tag all methods with the decorator `@staticmethod` instead. Otherwise calling any method on an *instance*, like `A.shear()`, would pass `A` as `data` instead, which is most likely not desired.

```py
class foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(data):
        ...
```

Example:

```py
methods = []
for attrname,attrvalue in vars(Augmentation).items():
    if callable(attrvalue):
        methods.append(attrvalue)
print([i.__name__ for i in methods])
```

Comment: Note that `vars()` only gives you the namespace of that one class which does not include the attributes of any parent classes. Use `dir()` (and filter out names starting with an underscore) to get public attribute names from the whole class hierarchy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point. Also if you really want to reinvent the wheel you can iterate through `Augmentation.mro()` and add functions from each parent class manually. And you still have to filter out the `__xxx__` methods. Obviously don't do this unless you need to have specific actions for each base class.